# Button for moving to next picture in gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got 2 buttons "Next" and "Previous". I'd like them to move to the next/previous image in my gallery. How would I setup a listener to the buttons to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is your custom gallery then you can do something like the below

add listeners to the button

```
previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

set image in onclick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view == previousButton) {
            --positionOfSelectedImage;
            // set background image of
        } else if (view == nextButton) {
            ++positionOfSelectedImage;
        }

imageToBeSet.setImageURI(Uri.parse(absolutepathOfImage));
}
```

Thanks
Deepak